# Within-subject mean centering of covariate in linear mixed models

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, centering

I have a within-subject repeated measures dataset where participants were asked to rate images (48 items) at 3 separate time points (t0,t1,t2). Their ratings at t0 is what is defined as *baseline*, as there is an intervention (A/B) taking place on a subset of images between t0 and t1, affecting t1 and t2.
I have following linear mixed model in R (hereafter called "base"):

lmer(rating ~ intervention * baseline + session * intervention + (1 | participant)  + (1 | item).

I'm particularly interested in the intervention:baseline interaction and would like to better understand how grand mean centering baseline (GMC) versus person mean centering (PMC) alters the model results and interpretation. More specifically I would like to better understand why PMC causes the participant-specific RE to almost double, why the marginal R2 decreases and why the estimate for the intervention:baseline increases?

Given that I am primarily interested in the within-subject effect of the intervention as a function of baseline, would it be reasonable to use PMC?

I attach a table of all three model results:
Left side we see the results for the base model, middle is the GMC, right side is the PMC.

[image]